# Have jumping vault gymnasts improved immensely in the past 80 years?

Tags: sport

This [9gag video](http://9gag.com/gag/avPvoPW) compares a 1932 vaulter to a 2012 vaulter. Wow! I could be a competitive athlete 80 years ago.

Basically, the site claims that the sport 80 years ago is far less impressive than it is now.

Is this true?

Note: another sample is http://9gag.com/gag/aW6VMB2. I wonder if this should be in another question.

Comment: Hey! Welcome back, Jim. It's been a long while! Obviously, the term "pathetic" is purely opinion-based. What is the claim here? Perhaps that this is true footage of an Olympic vault event in 1932?

Comment: We have a pretty good sports site where you can probably ask what the differences are.

Comment: You may recall that this site has some unusual scope rules: generally: find someone is making a notable claim that you doubt, quote it, ask if it is true. No-one is claiming evolution over 80 years has had an effect. No-one is saying 100m in 15 seconds was an Olympic record 80 years ago. No-one is saying athletes were "pathetic" 80 years ago.

Comment: It's not as flashy, but the 1932 example has a man jumping at least his own height and clearing the length of a sawhorse while touching it only once. Possibly without a springboard, i can't tell. I don't think many people are actually capable of that today.

Comment: "I can run 100 m in 15 seconds. Would I have been a gold medalist 80 years ago?" No, you'd have been beaten by Jesse Owens running 100m in 10.3 seconds.

Comment: One way to get a notion of the degree to which changes can be blamed on equipment on one hand or training/supporting nutrition/technique on the other hand would be to look at drive distances in golf where drivers are limited according to the performance they given in a standardized driving machine as compared to (say) service speeds in tennis where the kit it not subject to objective limits. Of course it is clear that some events (footraces, say) should be less directly effected by technology than others (pole vault, for instance).

Comment: I changed the question

Comment: Score so far: 5 questions from 9gag posted in Skeptics

Comment: I hate to answer the question since I don't think this is on topic, but there is an obvious difference in that the 2012 guy is taking off from a high-tech springboard and the older guy is taking off from the floor.

Comment: Consider also that there are wide variations in individual performance at any sport.  Today there is a) a larger world population; b) a greater percentage of the population potentially interested/able to compete; and c) more financial incentives & support for people with natural ability to train extensively at an Olympic sport.

Comment: I had a brief look at the scoring of vault gymnastics, to see whether there were empirical results that could be compared, but there seem to have been a lot of  rules and technology changes that stymied me.

Answer (score 5):

### Authenticity

First, I want to check the two videos are genuine.

The second vaulter is gold-medal winning South Korean Olympic competitor, [Yang Hak Seon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang_Hak-seon), in the [Men's Vault Final of the London 2012 Olympics](https://youtu.be/Nkd39-BwXto?t=28m23s).

The first vaulter would, by implication, be Italian Olympic competitor [Savino Guglielmetti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savino_Guglielmetti) ([Italian version](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savino_Guglielmetti)), but I have been unable to confirm that this is footage of him, performing his highest scoring vault in the 1932 Olympics.

### Speculative Factors

There may be many reasons why you perceive the 2012 vaulter to be more talented than the 1932 vaulter. One might speculate that advances in nutrition, training techniques, competition, specialisation (compare Guiglielmetti's [diversity](http://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/athletes/gu/savino-guglielmetti-1.html) to [Yang's](https://database.fig-gymnastics.com/public/gymnasts/biography/15925/true?backUrl=)) and remuneration have led to higher-quality competitors entering the sport. The actual difficulty levels may also be surprising to an untrained eye.

It is difficult to rule these factors out, but as no evidence for that is provided here, so they should be treated with suspicion.

### Vault Apparatus

One key reason for the more impressive displays is the [new vaulting apparatus](https://usagym.org/pages/home/publications/technique/2003/1/vaulttable.pdf) introduced around 2003.

> In working with the vaulting table, the greatest benefit
> of the apparatus becomes apparent in the round-off
> entry vaults. The athletes lose the fear of missing their
> hands on the vault, thus enabling them to be much
> more aggressive on their run, hurdle and round-off.
> Because the vaulting boards are so close to the end of
> the table on the round-off entry vault, the fear of
> flipping in front of the horse is also diminished. These
> changes are producing faster learning times and more aggressive vaults.

[Slate](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2004/08/whats_with_that_weird_new_vault.html) gives a backgrounder:

> Why the equipment change?
>
> In part to facilitate more impressive acrobatic feats, and in part to reduce injuries.
>
> [...]
>
> The larger surface area has also made it easier for vaulters to perform difficult maneuvers that require handsprings on the approach. In Thursday's competition, for example, Patterson performed a double twisting Yurchenko vault, a very difficult feat involving a back handspring. The width of the table provides gymnasts with a bit more room for error when executing such routines.

### Conclusion

The new vault technology explains much of the difference in audience appeal of vaulting gymnastics over the years.

Comment: One more thing to add is that [different moves were developed and added to the scoring at different times](http://www.flogymnastics.com/article/37091-the-evolution-of-vault). "Until the early 1970s, nothing spectacular was performed. Gymnasts would simply sprint down the runway, perform a front handspring onto the horse and push off into a layout position with no salto (flip) or twist"

Comment: @user568458: That's a great reference, and gives some good background. It leaves open the question though: were these techniques absent in 1932 because the athletes were not skilled enough - and hence couldn't possibly have managed these skills - or merely because the innovations these techniques are based upon hadn't been invented yet.

Comment: oh atheles can lose their hand on old equipment?

Comment: @JimThio: I'm not certain if you're cracking a joke. What is meant by the phrase is that they might "miss their hands" by not actually placing them on the vault in the correct position. Compare "losing your footing" when it comes to walking.

Comment: Oh I thought their hand would get stuck on something and then it'll snap off. Injury and stuff.